# How do I prove that the sum of squared differences from the mean is never bigger than the sum of squared differences from the median?

Tags: statistics, inequality, means, median, mean-square-error

I'm thinking there are $n$ numbers, call them $a_1$ through $a_n$ ... with mean $x$ and median $y$. I think it is true that $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (x-a_k)^2 \leq \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (y-a_k)^2$$

In words, this means **the sum of squared differences from the mean is never bigger than the sum of squared differences from the median**.

I have tested many sets of numbers and this is true for everything I tested. However, I do not know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $ f(x) = \sum (x - a_k)^2 = nx^2 - (2 \sum a_k)x + \sum a_k^2 $.

When is the minimum of $f(x)$ achieved?

> Minimum is achieved at $ \frac{ 2 \sum a_k} { 2n }, $ which is the mean.
>  Hence the sum of squared differences from the mean is never bigger than the sum of squared differences from any other value, and in particular, the median.

Answer (score 0):

We can show a stronger result -- that the variance of a data set is $\le$ the second moment about any other point, i.e.$\forall y$

$$\frac1n\sum(\bar x-a_k)^2\le\frac1n\sum(y-a_k)^2$$

Recall that the variance of random variable $X$ is given by $V[X]=E[(X-E[X])^2]$. Let $y$ be a point such that the second moment of $X$ about $y$,$E[(X-y)^2]<E[(X-E[X])^2]$. This gives$$E[X^2]+y^2-2yE[X]<E[X^2]-E[X]^2$$and hence $(E[X]-y)^2<0$, which is absurd.